# jquery Ajax call from view to controller method but not disply the view returned that method in mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have given Ajax call from Index.cshtml view to PrintPreview method which is present in MasterList Controller and i have also passed parameters.
The Index method also present in MasterList controller But
while returning view from PrintPreview method call is going to PrintPreview.cshtml page but the page is not loading i.e not displaying in browser and Index.cshtml page displaying in browser
please help.

enter code here

```
    $('#printbtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("PrintPreview", "MasterList")',                
            data: 
    { saleorderIdList: JSON.stringify(saleorder_id),
  orderIdList:JSON.stringify(order_id) },

            });
    });





    public ActionResult PrintPreview(string saleorderIdList, string orderIdList)
    {
        var locationIdOfLoginUser = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LocationId"]);
        ViewBag.loccationName = Session["LocationName"];
        ViewBag.locationType = Session["LocationType"];
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        IEnumerable<int> saleOrderIds = new int[] { };
        IEnumerable<int> orderIds = new int[] { };
        if (saleorderIdList != null)
        {
            saleOrderIds = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<int>>(saleorderIdList);
        }
        if (orderIdList != null)
        {
            orderIds = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<int>>(orderIdList);
        }
        MasterListService masterListService = new MasterListService();
        var ordercollection = masterListService.GetSelectedorders(locationIdOfLoginUser, saleOrderIds, orderIds);
        return View(ordercollection);

    }
```

Comment: The data has to match the "shape" expected. What is your `MasterListDTO` class and do you have a sample of the data sent (e.g. from Fiddler2)?

Answer (score 0):

The data has to match the "shape" expected. You are passing a single object (with 2 properties) but it is expecting a list (i.e. JSON array).

You should change your post instead to pass an array:

```
data: passresult: [{ saleorderIdList: JSON.stringify(saleorder_id),
      orderIdList:JSON.stringify(order_id) }],
```

If that fails, just as a test, change your action to this and see if it is hit (for your existing data):

```
public ActionResult PrintPreview(MasterListDTO passresult)
```

Comment: public ActionResult PrintPreview(string saleorderIdList, string orderIdList)

Comment: The singnature for PrintPreview method above mentoned

then in that method:::
 
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            IEnumerable<int> saleOrderIds = new int[] { };
            IEnumerable<int> orderIds = new int[] { };
            if (saleorderIdList != null)
            {
                saleOrderIds = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<int>>(saleorderIdList);
            }
            if (orderIdList != null)
            {
                orderIds = serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<int>>(orderIdList);
            }

Comment: @Gomtesh Hatgine: Use a tool like Fiddle2 to see the actual request sent to your server (and post the raw server request in your question for us to see). Q: Is your `PrintPreview` action marked with `[Httppost]`?